# Ruby on Rails: can not generate url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image: url generation error]
Guys, please help. I can't generate the url, don't know what to do. Need your help.

[rake routes](http://prntscr.com/cgrh51)

[quizzes_controller.rb](http://prntscr.com/cgrfyk)

[_navbar.html.haml](http://prntscr.com/cgrgb6)

[routes.rb](http://prntscr.com/cgrgux)

Comment: what do you get when you run  'rake routes'

Comment: same url on line 25

Comment: Please post your code in `routes.rb`

Comment: `root "quizzes#index"  
  resources :quizzes do  
    resources :problems  
  end`

Answer (score 0):

You must pass something quiz_id if you want walk to this page:

example:

```
  =link_to "question", new_quiz_problem_path(@quiz.id)
```

Comment: thanx, but did NOT help

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass quiz to helper method

```
new_quiz_problem_path(@quiz)
```

Comment: thanx, but NOT helped

Comment: are you going to past controller, view and "rake routes" code or we should read tea leaves?

Answer (score 0):

follow your routes.rb

```
root "quizzes#index" 

resources :quizzes do 
  resources :problems 
end
```

And you are in the `quizzes#index` page.
So you should let `new_quizzes_problem_path(quiz.id)` in a codeblock where `quiz` is defined. Because one quiz's problems cannot belong to another quiz (sorry for my bad english.)

ex:

```
 Quiz.all.each do |quiz|
  .......
  .......
  =link_to "New Question", new_quiz_problem_path(quiz.id)
 end
```